# React hooks- When passing props, it gets undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Can you help me with a problem I have in my code?
I'm trying to set a button in my page to get more information about a row. However, in the method I'm calling, it gets 'undefined' value.

Can you help me please to know what I'm doing wrong?
Here is my code:

```
 const mostrarDetalles = async (e:any, f:any) => {       // This is the method I'm calling with my button
    console.log(e);   // Here it prints 'undefined'
    console.log(f);   // Here it prints 'undefined'
    try {

        const result = await axios.get('https://inventario-services.herokuapp.com/invservice/plato/getPlato/?nombre=' + f, config);
        let data = result.data.receta
        for(let i = 0 ; i< data.length ; i++ ) {
            data[i].nombreIng = await getNombre(data[i].codigo_spro);
            data[i].cantIng = await getCantidad(data[i].codigo_spro);
            if(data[i].cantIng >= (data[i].cantidad * e)){
                data[i].posible = true;
            }
            else{
                data[i].posible = false;
            }
        }
        setStockRecetas(data);
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err); 
    }
}

return(
        <Container>
            <Segment textAlign='left'>
                    {predicciones.map(pr => (
                        <div>
                            <p>+ {pr.cantidad_plato} -> {pr.plato} - {pr.precision}</p>
                            <Button onClick={() => {mostrarDetalles(pr.cantidad, pr.nombre_plato)}} >Ver disponibilidad</Button>       // Here is the button that is calling the method
                        </div>
                    ))}
            </Segment>
        </Container>
    );
```

As an additional information, I use an arrow function because that's the way I found to add parameters when I'm calling the method. Am I wrong?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: please post your `predicciones` array

Answer (score 0):

Sorry everyone, I notice I was sendind a diferent variable in the method that the one I was expected.

Thank you for your time.